# "Toggle vote history" button on the timeline

Tags: script, timeline

### Description

Adds a "Toggle vote history" button to the timeline, which toggles visibility of vote events.

[image]

Inspired by a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on Meta Stack Exchange—[Add a way to hide vote history rows on timelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284515/310998).

### Instalation

Click the following link: <kbd>[Install](https://github.com/Gothdo/UserScripts/raw/master/se-timeline-toggle-vote-history.user.js)</kbd>.

### Bugs

Please report any bugs on [the Issues page on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Gothdo/UserScripts/issues) (though I doubt there could be bugs in such a simple userscript).